# How can i load an XML file to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, markup

Im trying to load an XML file to SQL Server, but i m not getting anything
Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31" catalog-id="master-catalog-sso-us">
    <header>
        <image-settings>
            <internal-location base-path="/"/>
            <view-types>
                <view-type>large</view-type>
                <view-type>medium</view-type>
                <view-type>small</view-type>
                <view-type>swatch</view-type>
            </view-types>
            <alt-pattern>${productname}</alt-pattern>
            <title-pattern>${productname}</title-pattern>
        </image-settings>
    </header>

    <category category-id="root">
        <display-name xml:lang="x-default">root Category</display-name>
        <description xml:lang="x-default">root Category</description>
        <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        <template/>
        <page-attributes/>
        <refinement-definitions>
            <refinement-definition type="attribute" bucket-type="none" attribute-id="shops" system="false">
                <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Shops</display-name>
                <value-set>search-result</value-set>
                <sort-mode>value-name</sort-mode>
                <sort-direction>ascending</sort-direction>
                <cutoff-threshold>5</cutoff-threshold>
            </refinement-definition>
        </refinement-definitions>
    </category>

    <category category-id="default">
        <display-name xml:lang="x-default">default Category</display-name>
        <description xml:lang="x-default">default Category</description>
        <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        <parent>root</parent>
        <template/>
        <page-attributes/>
    </category>

    <product product-id="0217328320-sso-us">
        <ean/>
        <upc/>
        <unit/>
        <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
        <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
        <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Magnetibook - 4 Seasons</display-name>
        <long-description xml:lang="x-default">48 magnets that stick to the metallic &amp;#34;canvas&amp;#34; where your child can choose between any of the four season &amp;#34;back drops&amp;#34; and then pick out the appropriate outfits and dress the family for a day outside. Comes in a magnetic closing &amp;#34;book&amp;#34; for safe keeping and easy storage.</long-description>
        <store-force-price-flag>false</store-force-price-flag>
        <store-non-inventory-flag>false</store-non-inventory-flag>
        <store-non-revenue-flag>false</store-non-revenue-flag>
        <store-non-discountable-flag>false</store-non-discountable-flag>
        <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        <online-from>2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z</online-from>
        <available-flag>true</available-flag>
        <searchable-flag>false</searchable-flag>
        <tax-class-id>standard</tax-class-id>
        <brand>Janod</brand>
        <manufacturer-name>Juratoys Company</manufacturer-name>
        <sitemap-included-flag site-id="rco-us">true</sitemap-included-flag>
        <sitemap-changefrequency site-id="rco-us">weekly</sitemap-changefrequency>
        <sitemap-priority site-id="rco-us">1.0</sitemap-priority>
        <page-attributes/>
        <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="ID">6339080</custom-attribute>
```

How do i load that ID field into SQL? I tried this:
But i believe my  cross apply c.nodes is wrong! What Markups should i use?
Thanks

```
SELECT a.id.query('id').value('.','varchar(50)') as id FROM 
( SELECT CAST(C AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\test\master.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) as T(c)  ) AS S(c)
cross apply c.nodes('product/id') as A(id)
```

Comment: Your XML is malformed, it has no closing tag. Which nodes are you trying to shred into rows?

Answer (score 0):

You ca try this:

```
SELECT c.id.query('id').value('.','varchar(50)') as id FROM 
( SELECT CAST(C AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\test\master.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) as T(c)  ) AS T(c)
cross apply c.nodes('product/id') as c(id)
```

But in your shared xml couldn't find an id tag within product tag.

**Here I am sharing an Example:**

**XML File content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 000</Document>
    <Name>Mary Angel</Name>
    <Address>Your City, YC 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Systems Analyst</Profession>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 001</Document>
    <Name>John Lenon</Name>
    <Address>Your City, YC 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Driver</Profession>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 002</Document>
    <Name>Alice Freeman</Name>
    <Address>Your City, YC 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Architect</Profession>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 003</Document>
    <Name>George Sands</Name>
    <Address>Your City, YC 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Doctor</Profession>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Document>000 000 004</Document>
    <Name>Mark Oliver</Name>
    <Address>Your City, YC 1212</Address>
    <Profession>Writer</Profession>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Copy above content and save as a xml file in d drive named testxmlfile.xml

**Then try below query:**

```
SELECT
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Document').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') Document,
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') Name,
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Address').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')Address,
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Profession').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)' )Profession
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:\testxmlfile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('Customers/Customer') AS MY_XML (Customer);
```

**Output:**

```
Document    Name            Address             Profession
000 000 000 Mary Angel      Your City, YC 1212  Systems Analyst
000 000 001 John Lenon      Your City, YC 1212  Driver
000 000 002 Alice Freeman   Your City, YC 1212  Architect
000 000 003 George Sands    Your City, YC 1212  Doctor
000 000 004 Mark Oliver     Your City, YC 1212  Writer
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but not getting anything.
So what is the first tag should i use? if there is no product tag?

Comment: Please tag complete content of your xml file if possible

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been clear about what exactly you want, but it *looks* like you want the attribute `product-id` from here:

```xml
    <product product-id="0217328320-sso-us">
```

You haven't taken into account namespaces, you need to add that.

It's also unclear if you have multiple `product` nodes. If you do, then you need this

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31')
SELECT A.product.value('@product-id','varchar(50)') as id
FROM 
( SELECT CAST(C AS XML)
  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\test\master.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) as T(c)
) AS S(c)
cross apply S.c.nodes('/catalog/product') as A(product)
```

If you have only one `product` node then you don't need `.values` at all:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31')
SELECT S.c.value('/catalog/product/@product-id','varchar(50)') as id FROM 
FROM 
( SELECT CAST(C AS XML)
  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\test\master.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) as T(c)
) AS S(c)
```